# How can I initialize a static const object in a class and use it?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
private:
    static const Color::Color myColor
public:
    void SomeMethod();
}

// MyClass.cpp

const Color MyClass::myColor = Color::Color::Blue;
// or
const Color MyClass::myColor(Color::Color::Blue);

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    Color c = this->myColor;
    Color c1 = Color::Color::Blue;
}
```

In this example, the `Color c` variable was not set. but `c1` was set successfully.

Comment: From where is SomeMethod() being called? It may be you are calling this method during static initialization before myColor has been initialized.

Comment: well I initialize an instance of MyClass and let's just say I call it on construction.  That should work.

Comment: As I recall, static-linked static initializers to anything but `0` can run in any order at any time before entering `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I recommend providing a fully compilable example that shows your issue. Below I've included what looks like your test case, which works as expected.

```
#include <cassert>

enum class Color {
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2
};

class MyClass {
    private:
        static const Color myColor;
    public:
        void SomeMethod();
};

const Color MyClass::myColor = Color::Blue;

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    Color c = this->myColor;
    Color c1 = Color::Blue;

    assert(c == Color::Blue);
    assert(c1 == Color::Blue);
}

int main() {
    MyClass x;
    x.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: My copy constructor was not working the way that it should but since you took the time to write all of this and it is correct, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    class MyClass
{
private:
    static const Color::Color myColor = Color::Color::Blue;
public:
    void SomeMethod();
};
```

Comment: only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class